# Specific regex with fixed groups

Tags: regex

I'm just starting to learn regex, and I need a fixed string and some other fixed conditions like this:

```
VATICAN-Application-Necropolis-ABC-ABC-<a-zA-z>
```

ABC must be always 3 uppercase characters, the dashes also must be there and the last part can be upper and lower.
I have this

```
\bVATICAN-Application-Necropolis-([A-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+){2})(?!\S)
```

But that one lets the `NNC` part to be more that 3 characters and the other part does not enforce only 3 uppercase.
I tried

```
\bVATICAN-Application-Necropolis-([A-Z]+(?:-[A-Z]+){2})(?!\S)
```

but that won't work.

For instance:
`VATICAN-Application-SPS-LMD-Supervisor` should match, `VATICAN-Application-SPSP-LMD-Supervisor` should not as SPSP is not 3 characters long. Neither should `VATICAN-Application-SPS-LMSD-Supervisor` match because LMSD is not 3 characters long. Same if those had lowercase letters in it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `(?!\S)` at the end? That means it can't be followed by `Supervisor`

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

```
/\bVATICAN-Application-Necropolis(-[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}-([a-zA-Z]+))(?!\S)/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\bVATICAN-Application-(?:[A-Z]{3}-){2}
```

`[A-Z]{3}` matches exactly 3 uppercase letters, and this is followed by `-` so it won't allow extra letters after it. This group is then doubled with `{2}`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ETqpQA/1)

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it was missing the last part